# Почему при попытке вставить данные в таблицу через сервис сохраняются пустые поля объекта?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 1с, rest

Есть база данных 1С. К ней предоставлен RESTful доступ по протоколу OData. Я пишу клиент на C#. Подключился к данному сервису через "Добавить ссылку на службу".

Запрос данных проходит на ура через DataServiceContext(созданный автоматически). Пытаюсь добавить клиента в таблицу "Catalog_Партнёры".

```
            var context = new CRM_2Demo.EnterpriseV8(odataUri)
            {
                Credentials = odataCredentials
            };
            var newClient = new CRM_2Demo.Catalog_Партнеры
            {
                CRM_Имя = "Влад"
            };

            context.AddToCatalog_Партнеры(newClient);

            DataServiceResponse response = context.SaveChanges();
```

Запись в БД добавляется однако поле "CRM_Имя" всё равно остается пустым. Почему?

P.S. у меня есть подозрение, что это из-за того, что классы имеют кириллицу в наименовании, однако Visual Studio ведь сгенерировал все классы для работы с сервисом без проблем... Я также пытался инициализировать другие поля но они все остаются пустыми.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри [Linq to ODATA](http://infostart.ru/public/403524/)

Посмотри фиддлером, что отправляется
Возможно Ref_Key  нужно присвоить. И попробуй обновить запись
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd756361(v=vs.100).aspx

И все поля должны быть заполнены. Получи одну запись и посмотри какие поля заполнены

Comment: Обновление, удаление и создание пустых записей проходит успешно. Смотрел Wireshark-ом он не может разобрать русский текст и вместо него точки ".....". Сейчас Fiddler-ом гляну

Comment: В Fiddler-е видно, что запрос отправляется верно (<d:CRM_Имя>Тест</d:CRM_Имя>), а результат возвращается с пустым полем CRM_Имя...

Comment: При присвоении создаваемому клиенту нового GUID 
'newClient.RefKey = Guid.NewGuid()' ему присваивается новый guid и в  в ответе также содержится этот же guid.

Comment: А попробуй через JSON context.Format.UseJson();. Я для записи не пользовался.

Comment: Задай вопрос здесь http://www.forum.mista.ru/index.php , только про Linq не упоминай. Дай данные Фиддлера

Comment: насчет JSON: OData насколько я понял принимает только Atom для вставки данных, по крайней мере 1С. Проблема пока актуальна но отъехала на попозже.

Comment: Ну вот здесь http://infostart.ru/public/403524/ прекрасно понимает JSON